# Add two columns of same matrix and append it in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I want to add two column of same matrix and append it

```
Input matrix:
[[74, 25],
 [93, 76],
 [77, 41]]

Required:
[[74, 99, 25],
 [93, 169, 76],
 [77, 118, 41]]

Note: 74 + 25= 99
      93 + 76= 169
      77 + 41= 118
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: provide a minimal python example please

Comment: Please try things by yourself before asking.

Comment: @JoseManueldeFrutos I'm new to python, and i'm clueless about this

Comment: those matrices, are numpy matrices or just two nested lists?

Answer (score 1):

From your example is not clear the input war in numpy format.
I guess yes due to the label numpy.

In this case, numpy cannot change shape so you must create a new data structure.
These can be a good starting point

### first

prepare the original matrix with all columns and fill it with the right values. Take care to do vectorial computation

### second

```
data = array([[74, 25],
       [93, 76],
       [77, 41]])

A=data[:,0]
C=data[:,1]
B=A+C

np.vstack([A,B,C]).T
# Out[67]: 
# array([[ 74,  99,  25],
#        [ 93, 169,  76],
#        [ 77, 118,  41]])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([[74, 25],
[93, 76],
[77, 41]])
b=np.ones((a.shape[0],a.shape[1]+1))
b[:,[0,2]]=a
b[:,1]=a.sum(axis=1)
print(b)
```